# Вывод товара по категориям

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Всем привет!

Вроде заезженая тема, но я никак не могу допереть, что я делаю не так.

В общем есть таблица `categories`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же есть таблица `products`, которая посредством `category_id` связана с таблицей `categories`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же их модели:
`Product`

```
public function productImage() {

  public function getCategory()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
  }
}
```

и `Category`

```
class Category extends Model
{
  public function products()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
  }
}
```

И наконец шаблон:

```
@section('content')
<section class="section-category">
  <div class="container-lg">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <a href="/{{ $category->url }}" class="btn btn-lg btn-success catbtn" type="button">
              <img class="catbtnimg" src="/img/categories/{{ $category->img }}">
            </a>
            <h6 class="text-center text-success">{{ $category->name }}</h6>
        </div>
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        @foreach($categories as $product)
          @foreach($product->products as $item)
            @include('card', compact('item'))
          @endforeach
        @endforeach
      </div><!--end row-->
  </div><!--end container-->
</section>
@endsection
```

Шаблон `card`, который подключается через `@include` выглядит так:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6">
  <div class="card mb-5">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="/img/products/{{ $item->cardImage->path }}" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title  text-center">{{ $item->name }}</h5>
      <div class="prch"><span class="card-text">{{ $item->price }}</span><span class="card-text"><i class="{{ $item->is_available_icon }}"></i>{{ $item->is_available_text }}</span></div><br>
      <div class="prch second">
      <span><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
      <span class="card-text feedback">10 отзывов</span>
      </div>
    </div><!--end card-body-->
    <div class="card-footer"></div>
    <div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-handshake"></i><span class="reg">Оформило 10 человек</span><br>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success mt-2 mb-1">Оформить сейчас!</a>
    </div>
  </div><!--end card-->
</div>
```

Роут выглядит так:

```
Route::get('/{categories}', 'MainController@categories');
```

А контроллер так :

```
public function categories($code){
    $categories = Category::where('code', $code)->get();
    return view('categories', compact('categories'));
  }
```

И наконец вопрос.
Когда перехожу в категории вижу следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я выбираю, к примеру, первую категорию вижу следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И проблема уже в конкретной подкатегории. Когда я выбираю её, товары этой категории не выводятся(просто пустое пространство на месте где были категории).

Как это исправить не знаю (опыта пока не так много), если у кого есть какие то мысли, с радостью выслушаю.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я же уже вам отвечал как сделать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1197027/Категории-товаров-laravel/1197170#1197170

Comment: Да, вероятно рабочий метод, но переделывать много чего прийдется, в том числе и БД(если я не ошибаюсь), нашел иной способ, но пока не доделал.

Comment: Нет, только метод получения продуктов `Product::whereIn('category_id', Category::where('code', $code)->pluck('id')->toArray())->get()` примерно так, если смотреть именно тот ответ

Comment: А ещё правильней `Product::whereHas('category', fn($builder) => $builder->where('code', $code'))->get()`